# Podman server API version is too old. Client "4.0.0" server "3.4.4"

Tags: spring, docker, intellij-idea, devops, podman

I'm trying to use Podman to build an image of a Spring Boot project in IntelliJ.
Jetbrain's guide suggests to "Select TCP socket and specify the Podman API service URL in Engine API URL" within Build,Execution,Deployment > Docker (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/podman.html).

However, when giving the TCP socket found on Podman's documentation (see https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-system-service.1.html), IntelliJ says it cannot connect.

Finally, when here is the error that appears in terminal:

```
(base) abc ~ % podman ps
Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
Error: unable to connect to Podman socket: server API version is too old. Client "4.0.0" server "3.4.4"
```

I cannot find any solution to update server version.
Any suggestion is welcome! Thanks.

[Intellij screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzpuq.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facing the same problem due to podman version upgrade.

Seems like a version downgrade would be required to recover the containers, but haven't tried it yet.
This issue points on deleting the machine and creating it again, but the containers would be lost
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13510

Comment: Aso had to brew upgrade but this worked. Thanks

Comment: Deleting and the machine and creating it worked for me - Just remember to run "podman machine stop" to be able to remove it.